# How to apply conditional formatting in Excel based on value in another cell using MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab, conditional-formatting

I am trying to automate conditional formatting in Excel sheets generated using MATLAB. I have to format the color of a cell based on the value in the adjacent cell. And I prefer to achieve this by using actxserver in MATLAB.

For example:
I need to format the color of cells B2:B20 based on values from cells A2:A20.

This is the code I am using

```
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
set(Excel,'Visible', 0); 

Workbook = invoke(Excel.Workbooks, 'open', [fpath filesep file ext]);
sheet = get(Excel.Worksheets, 'Item', sheetname);
invoke(sheet, 'Activate');

%% range: cells that need to be formatted
%% range1: cells that determine the formatting of range

ExAct = Excel.Activesheet; 
ExActRange = get(ExAct,'Range',range);
ExActRange.Select;

xlExpression = 2;

Excel.Selection.FormatConditions.Delete;
Excel.Selection.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, [], ['=' range '=if(range1 = 6, 1)']);
Excel.Selection.FormatConditions.Item(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3;

invoke(Workbook, 'Save');
invoke(Excel, 'Quit');

delete(Excel);
```

Please let me know my mistake, and better if you could suggest an alternative that could get my job done.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula should not reference itself, in Excel it would be `=IF(A2=6,1,0)`.

So your Add parameters might be

```
.Add(xlExpression, [], '=IF(A2=6,1,0)')
```

If you want to use a variable range then:

```
.Add(xlExpression, [], strcat('=IF(', range1, '=6,1,0)'))
```

In Excel, you can choose the entire range, and then create the conditional format formula based on the first cell, and then the formula will change for each cell, assuming you don't use $ signs to freeze the value.

Comment: Hi Lance, this seems to work. But instead of referencing a cell by say A2 here, I want to reference it with a variable say range1 here. How do I do that?. Thank you

Comment: @BhaskarChennuri, edited in answer for that.  Note I don't have time to test it, so let me know if strcat isn't doing the job.